# prolog find facts and query for family tree

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I need the help to find the prolog code for the below : ancestors(x,y) using only a is_a(x,y) where X is a Y

image related to question attached below
[animal tree question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUCSO.png)

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. Please include all relevant information within the question. This way your question is easier to understand and could also help other people in the future in case your external linked resources are not longer available... Thank you.

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079111/prolog-facts-animal-trees-and-relation Please do not create multiple questions for the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prolog facts animal trees and relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079111/prolog-facts-animal-trees-and-relation)